SDL automatically scales my image larger than it is
I'm just displaying a simple 60 by 60 pixel image.
Using IMG_Load with SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface and SDL_Renderer.
When it appears in my application window it is larger.
Windows system display scale is set to 150% because of 3840 x 2160 resolution.
Is there a way to tell SDL not to scale the application display along with the Windows system display?
Original image on the left. Actual 60 by 60. SDL image on the right. Looks larger than image on the left:


SDL_SetHint(SDL_HINT_WINDOWS_DPI_AWARENESS, "system");

